# Laravel Request - How to know parent/destination class name in rules()

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel Request - How to know parent/destination class name inside rules() method, before returning rules array?

```
public function rules(){
    /**
     * 1:: We need to know parent/destination class name
     */

     return [
        //
    ];
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know the name of the FormRequest/Controller? Put an example, please.

Comment: @HCK
    public function store(SomeRequest  $request){
        $this->validateStore($request);} i want to get the class which contains store(SomeRequest $request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the rule you can do:

```php
<?php 

public function rules()
{
    $action = \Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionName();
    $controller = explode('@', $action)[0];

     return [
        //
    ];
}
```

However there is a method called `prepareForValidation()` which you can use inside the request to sanitize data before passing it to validate. [See this](https://medium.com/@melihovv/how-to-sanitize-input-data-in-declarative-manner-in-laravel-e4486068f751) for reference.